# Receiving a variable from mssql.query in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, function, azure

Below is a simplified version of what I want to do.  I want to save the value that I get from mssql.query and retrieve it OUTSIDE of the mssql.query function.  I am using the variable "total" to do so.

```
var total;

    mssql.query("EXEC getMeetingInfo ?", [meetingID],  
    {
        success: function(results1) {            
            console.log(results1);
            total = results1;
      },
      error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : err });
      }
    });

    response.send(statusCodes.OK, total ); //does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mssql.query is asynchronous, so your response.send is running before total is set.  You need to move it inside the success function.

UPDATE:
To handle multiple and chain them together, do something like this (psuedo code):

```
var total = 0;
mssql.query(query, [],
{
    success: function(results1) {            
        total = total + {queryresult};
        mssql.query(query, [],
        {                success: function(results1) {            
                total = total + {queryresult};

                //Keep nesting as needed, and on last nest call this
                response.send(statusCodes.OK, total );
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Note it may be appropriate to create a separate javascript class for the callbacks to make this more manageable to read/maintain, but this callback model is the proper way to do this in an asynchronous world.

Comment: The problem is I have multiple mssql.querry's that I want to run / concatinate so I need to be able to access it outside of the function.  Is it possible to pause until done or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make it synchronous, but that's deprecated anyway.  You need to nest callbacks to accomplish that... I will update answer

Comment: It returns      [object Object][object Object][object Object] and not the actual data... i am getting back JSON data

Comment: That's pretty typical of asynchronous javascript calls; if your SQL statements are correct, I expect those json's have your data in them.  Parsing them would be up to you for the specific data you are expecting.